# How can I customize the color and font style of Python decorators in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, themes

I would like to customize my current color scheme and apply a dedicated color and fontstyle italic to **Python Decorators**. I found out how to do it for comments by editing the settings.json (see example below). What is the correct keyword for the decorators, please?

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "comments": "#b249ee",
},
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use the TextMate Scope inspector to find the scope of the text you want to color

Comment: what python extensions do you have installed? Please show what you see in the scope inspector (run `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` in command palette) when you put your cursor/caret over a Python decorator.

Answer (score 0):

In [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Your Theme Name Here]": { // remove this wrapper to apply regardless of colour theme
        "textMateRules": [{
            "scope": "punctuation.definition.decorator.python", // for the decorator name. only applies when semantic highlighting from the Python extension is not in effect.
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#FF0000",
                // "fontStyle": "bold"
            }
        },{
            "scope": "meta.function.decorator.python support.type.python", // for the "@" sign
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#FF0000",
                // "fontStyle": "bold"
            }
        }],
    },
},
"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false,
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Your Theme Name Here]": { // remove this wrapper to apply regardless of colour theme
        "enabled": false,
        "rules": {
            "class.decorator:python": { // remove ":python" to apply to all languages
                "foreground": "#FF0000",
                // "fontStyle": "bold",
            },
        },
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Unfortunately it does not work. I removed the Monokai wrappers and also tried it without the python language wrapper - no success

Comment: my fault in the beginning - I edited the wrong json file. It works nuw for the "@" Symbol now but I cannot get it to work for the decorator name

Answer (score 0):

Use the scope checkup to view text information (**Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes**),

[image]

Then edit the `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` and `editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations` settings to achieve the effect you want.

*https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_editor-syntax-highlighting*